# How to use Manim to animate a point moving on a number line?

Tags: animation, plot, manim

I'd like to use Manim to animate the position of a parameter on a number line.  I figured out how to animate the end position of the parameter as a line using ParametricFunction:

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np
import math

class line( Scene ):
    def construct( self ):

        tline = NumberLine(
            x_range=[ 0, 1 ],
            length=4,
            color=BLUE,
            include_numbers=False )

        t1 = ParametricFunction( lambda t: tline.number_to_point(np.sin(t * PI)),
                                 t_range=[0, 1],
                                 scaling=tline.scaling, color=YELLOW )

        self.play( DrawBorderThenFill( VGroup( tline ) ), run_time = 2 )
        self.play( AnimationGroup(Create(t1)), run_time = 6 )
```

This works okay for monotonically increasing values, but is no good if the end point doubles back on itself, as the animation becomes invisible at that stage.

Is there a way to change the line plot to animate a moving point instead of tracing out a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parameter simply moves between certain fixed values, you could follow a simple approach as in [this example in the documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/latest/reference/manim.mobject.value_tracker.ValueTracker.html?highlight=valuetracker#valuetrackerexample).

If you want more control over the exact way the marker moves across the number line, I'd recommend replicating something similar with a `ValueTracker` and the `UpdateFromAlphaFunc` animation, like this:

```py
from manim import *

class Example(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tline = NumberLine(
            x_range=[ 0, 1 ],
            length=4,
            color=BLUE,
            include_numbers=False )

        t_parameter = ValueTracker(0)
        t_marker = Dot(color=YELLOW).add_updater(
            lambda mob: mob.move_to(tline.number_to_point(t_parameter.get_value())),
        ).update()
        self.play( DrawBorderThenFill( VGroup( tline ) ), run_time = 2 )
        self.add(t_marker)
        self.play(
            UpdateFromAlphaFunc(
                t_parameter, 
                lambda mob, alpha: mob.set_value(np.sin(alpha * PI)),
                run_time=6
            )
        )
```